# Access instance url with heroku connect

Tags: heroku, salesforce

I'm trying to figure out if [Heroku Connect](https://connect.heroku.com/) gives you access to things like the Salesforce Instance URL (https://na30.salesforce.com), the Oauth Token, etc., but so far I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation of by Googling seeing as Connect is still fairly new. Anyone know if they give you this info anywhere or if you can access it by using their API?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Connect synchronizes Salesforce data with a Heroku Postgres database so there isn't any need for an instance URL or OAuth token.  You certainly could build an app that uses both OAuth / REST APIs and Heroku Connect but you'd have to setup the connections / auth separately.  You might want to check out the Salesforce & Heroku Integration Trailhead: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/salesforce_heroku_integration

Comment: I figured as much.